# Crash in NSFetchedResultsController performFetch (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I'm getting app crashed on the "try" line. How do I understand why? CoreData SQL debugging is activated but shows nothing suspicious.

```
do {
    try controller.performFetch()
} catch {
    let fetchError = error as NSError
    print("\(fetchError), \(fetchError.userInfo)")
}
```

Comment: What's the error from the crash?

Comment: And why are you casting `error` to `NSError`? Why not leave it as `Error`?

Comment: That error handling is taken from internet ... But there is 0 further information about crash .. only "objc_exception_throw" in stack

Comment: hmm, using iOS 10?  Try provide these launch arguments to get perhaps a bit more insight when/why things go off kilter   -com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1
-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1

Comment: Thanks, now I know two more debug flags. :/ Though they did not help in this case but I found the reason

Answer (score 0):

That is the reason for crash (found empirically)

> sectionNameKeyPath: ""

instead of

> sectionNameKeyPath: nil